How to give CSS or bootstrap class to Modal Popup Extender in ASP .NET Webforms
I am working on a web project using the Dashbyte template, and I am encountering an issue with modals. While the modal itself is working correctly, none of the custom or Bootstrap classes I apply are reflected in it. Even the background CSS from the extender functions as expected, but the modal's appearance does not seem to change based on the classes I assign.
<asp:Button Text="Open Modal" ID="btnmodal" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="modal_Click" runat="server" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="HideModal" runat="server"/>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Extender" runat="server" PopupControlID="MyModal" TargetControlID="HideModal" BackgroundCssClass="bg-white opacity-50"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="MyModal" runat="server">
 <div class=" modal-dialog modal-dailog-centered">
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalHeading" runat="server">Add New Record</h4>
             <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" Text="" runat="server" />
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"    ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationGroup="s" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Name"></asp:TextBox>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtAge" ValidationGroup="s" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Age"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="close" class="btn btn-danger" OnClick="btnClose_Click" />
             <asp:Button ID="btnsave" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnsave_Click" Text="Save" runat="server" ValidationGroup="s" />
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</asp:Panel>


What css classes specifically? Also looks like modal-dailog-centered is spelled wrong.

So other classes are not applying either.
